Getting Report has been limited to 28 columns after redirecting using retUrl in formula
Hi All What I am Doing is I created a Formula(Hyperlink) field. This field calls a Vf  Page and thw VF Page calls a screen flow.
Formula is as follow
HYPERLINK( "https://" & MID($Api.Partner_Server_URL_370, 9, FIND('/', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_370, 9) - 9) & "/apex/Research_UpdateNotesfromLink?ResearchID=" & Id & "&retURL=" & "/lightning/r/Report/00ONw000000HqXGMA0/view", "Update Notes", "_blank" )
Vf Page is
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardcontroller="Data_Sources__c" lightningStyleSheets="true">
<flow:interview name="Research_Update_Rep_Notes" finishLocation="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL}">
</flow:interview></apex:page>

This is Working Good in Desktop but when tested it on mobile device We faced a problem when we update the note and it redirect to the report page it shows yellow warning msg Report has been limited to 28 fields what we want is it should redirect to report page without any ristriction

Any help would be gretfull.
Thanks in Advance.

Do you get the same error when you open the report manually in Mobile?

Hi David When we open report manually on mobile we don't get this msg you are seeing on screenshot we get this error when we redirected to the report
